# ASP.NET MVC developer creating a Phonegap application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, cordova

I will be starting a PhoneGap application. My skill set includes just MVC framework of .net.
Since I will be making an app for mobile, I believe I wont be able to get benefits of MVC framework for state management, etc or will I?

I guess I will have to use a WCF service for the back end. Or do I need to use something else. How is state management done on HTML5 mobile applications.
Please suggest.

Comment: Google is a great resource - for example:  [Managing State Management in HTML5 Using Web Storage](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b19d5a/managing-state-management-in-html5-using-web-storage/).  There are doubtless several different ways to manage state in HTML5.

Comment: You can make use of MVC webapi for services instead of WCF as u have already worked wid MVC

Comment: @DiveshSalian I should structurize my app in a way I do business and db operations in Web Api controller and call it simple controllers for Web App for Views etc..Am I on the right direction?